# auto-correlation of squared residuals after fitting GARCH model

Tags: time-series, arima, garch, acf-pacf

Hell, I'm completely new to R and am not experienced in statistics but I got some stock price data and tried to fit an ARIMA+GARCH model. I'm a little confused because as the title suggests, I looked at the ACF for the squared residuals after modeling and there appeared to be just as much auto-correlation as with the residuals from the ARIMA fit.

Here is the price data: https://github.com/carsonaj/Finance/blob/master/price.csv

So what I have done:

```
s <- ts(log(price$close))
ds <- diff(s)

tsdisplay(s)
tsdisplay(ds)
```

So the ACF for `ds` seems to imply that we could model it as an ARMA(0,?) right?

```
fit <- auto.arima(ds, seasonal=FALSE)
tsdisplay(residuals(fit))
tsdisplay(residuals(fit)^2)
```

So `fit` is an ARMA (0,0) process with auto-correlation in the squared residuals.

```
garchSpec <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH",
                               garchOrder=c(2,2)),
           mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)), 
           distribution.model="std")

garchFit <- ugarchfit(spec=garchSpec, data=ds)
```

Now when I use the command `tsdisplay(residuals(garchFit)^2)`, there seems to be the same ACF as in the residuals squared for `fit`. Could someon explain this please?

Comment: Are you looking for the standardized or unstandardized residuals?

Comment: I think standardized

Comment: Check the documentation, that function returns the unstandardized residuals by default, which is why they still show squared autocorrelation. It has a parameter to return the standardized residuals instead.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it with your tip. Is there something I can read which would explain why the standardized residuals would have the correct ACF whereas the unstandardized would not? Like I mentioned, I'm new to stats.

Comment: It is not that the standardized residuals have a "correct" ACF. Under the GARCH model, the standardized residuals are assumed i.i.d.. The function residuals() applied to a GARCH object in R generally returns the mean residuals. This is, if you have $r_t = \mu_t +\sigma_t e_t$, then the residuals() function will return $r_t - \mu_t$, whereas the standardized residuals are $e_t$.